# How to convert a stream back to json?

Tags: json, .net-3.5, httpwebrequest, streamreader, httpwebresponse

In a .NET 3.5 Compact Framework / Windows CE app, I need to consume some WebAPI methods that return json. RestSharp looks like it would be great for this, except that it's not quite CF-ready (see [Is Uri available in some other assembly than System in .NET 3.5, or how can I resolve Uri in this RestSharp code otherwise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19305385/is-uri-available-in-some-other-assembly-than-system-in-net-3-5-or-how-can-i-re) for details).

So, I will probably use HttpWebRequest. I can return the value from the WebAPI methods with this code:

```
string uri = "http://localhost:48614/api/departments";
var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
if ((webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) && (webResponse.ContentLength > 0))
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
    MessageBox.Show("Content is " + reader.ReadToEnd());
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Status code == {0}", webResponse.StatusCode));
}
```

...but in order to use what's returned from reader.ReadToEnd():

[image]

...I need to convert it back to json so that I can then query the data with LINQ to JSON using either JSON.NET (http://json.codeplex.com/) or SimpleJson (http://simplejson.codeplex.com/)

Is that realistically possible (converting StreamReader data to JSON)? If so, how?

### UPDATE

I'm trying to deserialize the "json" (or string that looks like json) with this code:

```
string uri = "http://localhost:48614/api/departments";
var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
webRequest.Method = "GET";
var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
if ((webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) && (webResponse.ContentLength > 0))
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
    DataContractJsonSerializer jasonCereal = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Department));
    var dept = (Department)jasonCereal.ReadObject(reader.ReadToEnd());
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("accountId is {0}, deptName is {1}", dept.AccountId, dept.DeptName));
}
```

...but get two err msgs on the "var dept =" line:

```
0) The best overloaded method match for 'System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObject(System.IO.Stream)' has some invalid arguments

1) Argument '1': cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IO.Stream'
```

So reader.ReadToEnd() returns a string, and DataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject() expects a stream, apparently. Is there a better approach for this? Or, if I'm on the right track (although currently a section of track has been removed, so to speak), how should I get past this hurdle?

### UPDATE 2

I added the System.Web.Extensions reference and then "using System.Web.Script.Serialization;" but this code:

```
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var dept = jss.Deserialize<Department>(s);
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("accountId is {0}, deptName is {1}",  
    dept.AccountId, dept.DeptName));
```

...but the second line fails with:

"*Type 'bla+Department' is not supported for deserialization of an array.*"

What type should receive the call to jss.Deserialize()? How is it defined?

Comment: from where I see it, it is JSON no ? (except for the "Content is" introduction of course...which I suppose you add for debugging reasons)

Comment: It looks like JSON, but is that what StreamReader.ReadToEnd() returns? I doubt it. It's probably just the string representation of a byte array or something like that. IOW, would a JSON deserializer be able to make heads or tails of it?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, ReadToEnd() returns a string, which in this case seems correctly formatted as JSON, which I'm quite sure you could use to feed a deserializer... the best would be to test, cause I think we're discussing a non-problem...

Comment: I updated my post with detail about trying to deserialize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,

the `ReadToEnd()` method is used to read the stream into a string and output it. If you need a stream out to pass it to a method requiring a stream, you shouldn't use this method.
From what I read on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) , it seems the `BaseStream` property of your reader would be more appropriate to use then.